# identifying a specific 3d manifold: A torus fibered over a circle with a $Z_2$ twist.

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, low-dimensional-topology

I am looking for literature on a specific 3-manifold, can someone help me with its name?

The three manifold in question is a torus fibered over a circle $S_1$. As I move along the circle the longitude and the meridian of the torus gets interchanged such that when I am back at my starting point, the meridian is glued to the longitude and vice versa. In a sense it is a 3d variant of the moebius strip.

Does anyone know what 3d manifold I am talking about?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The torus' mapping class group allows classification of these surface bundles and since the mapping class group has only three involution elements which are determined by  maps $\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Z^2$ and specified by the three matrices:
$$f=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1&0\\ 0&-1\end{array}
\right)\quad,\quad g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\ 0&-1\end{array}
\right)\quad,\quad h=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\ 0&-1\end{array}
\right),$$
then there are only three of such bundles.
These three matrices are involutions (both these three squared are the identity matrix and why the structural group is $\Bbb Z_2$) and these three matrices give three 3-manifolds well known in terms of Seifert invariants. The three examples are Seifert fiber spaces.

The three bundles $E_f=T\times_f S^1$, $E_g=T\times_g S^1$ and $E_h=T\times_h S^1$ are respectively:

$E_f=(Oo,0|(1,2),(1,2),(1,-2),(1,-2))$,

$E_g=(NnI,2|(1,0))$ and

$E_h=(NnI,2|(1,1))$.

The second, $E_g$, is known to be the cartesian product $K\times S^1$, where $K$ is the Kleinbottle.

Comment: the mapping class group for the torus happens to be the classical group $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Although those three matrices may be the only involutions (up to conjugacy), they are not the only periodic elements in the mapping class group, not even up to conjugacy. There are also elements of order 3 such as $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, of order 4 such as $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and of order 6 such as $\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ (and I have not even mentioned any that reverse orientation).

Comment: @LeeMosher I already knew that

Comment: Okay, just wondering why you wrote the wrong thing in your answer then.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMosher, improve done

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "It's the manifold you just described." But the description can be made a little simpler. Under the diffeomorphism
$$
(\theta, \phi) \mapsto (\theta + \phi, \theta - \phi)
$$
of the torus (or its inverse), the meridian maps to a meridian plus longitude, and a longitude maps to a meridian minus a longitude. Taking these new coordinates, your clutching function looks like $m' \to m'$, $\ell' \to -\ell'$, where $m'$ and $\ell'$ are the new meridian and longitude.

I'm not certain whether this is any clearer a description. Actually, it seems as if it might be...you've got an $S^1 \times S^1$ bundle over $S^1$. The first factor is a trivial bundle, so we can just say we've got a product of $S^1$ with $F$, an $S^1$ bundle over $S^1$. And the clutching map for $F$ is just $\theta \mapsto -\theta$. That means that $F$ is the Klein bottle.

Hmm. You've got $S^1 \times K$, where $K$ is the Klein bottle. I guess that *is* a simpler description.